# zipalign: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libbacktrace.so.0: undefined symbol: _ZN11unwindstack12ElfInterfaceD2Ev

Tags: android, apktool, kali-linux, zipalign

Getting this error while using zipalign

zipalign: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libbacktrace.so.0: undefined symbol: _ZN11unwindstack12ElfInterfaceD2Ev

Answer (score 2):

Remove this file "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libbacktrace.so.0" and replace it with a new one from "https://packages.debian.org/buster/android-libbacktrace"

Choose right architecture then download it and open the fie location.

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks!!!
your solution fixed the error.